# how to handle iOS notification callback on phonegap cordova?

Tags: ios, cordova, callback, notifications

I don't know if the title say it properly but..

I have a cordova 1.9 app with push notifications using the [PushNotification Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/PushNotification) and UrbanAirship. Everything works fine.

Now I'd like to open a particular page of my app when I lauch/resume my app from a notification.

Is that possible using Javascript ?
I'm totally lost when reading objective-c.

Answer (score 3):

Notifications causes problem to understand JSON structure.

It is not:

```
if(notifications.length > 0){
```

But:

```
if(notifications.notifications.length > 0){
```

Array is on: `notifications.notifications[]` structure.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are trying to load the page but the simplest way would be to call for the pending notifications as it is in javascript and then use `window.location.href` to load the require page.

I am using this procedure to perform certain task when I have pending notification at application start:

```
function registerAirship() {
    console.log("ready to register for airship");
    window.plugins.pushNotification.registerDevice({alert:true, badge:true, sound:true},function(status) {
       if (status.deviceToken) {
           window.token = status.deviceToken;
           if (status) {
               registerUAPush(token, "https://go.urbanairship.com/", key, key1, function(){
                    window.plugins.pushNotification.getPendingNotifications(function(notifications) {
                        if(notifications.length > 0){
                            var note = notifications[0];
                            if(note.applicationLaunchNotification == "1"){
                                // use the note.aps and redirect to required page
                            }
                        }
                    });
               });
           } else {
             alert("Registration Error: " + status);
           }
       }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was in your position a few days ago. I decided it was easiest to hack objective-c.

So.

1) I found the function that handled my push notification (AppDelegate.m) and called a js function after objective-c had launched execution for handling the notification. After that line, I did this:

```
[viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"opensometab()"];
```

2) In the root of my web app application I added this to the pushnotification.js file (you should be able to put it anywhere but I wanted it here). 
** My JS function was to activate a tab within the Viewport so yours may be different.

```
function opensometab(){
    var tabPanel = Ext.Viewport.down('tabpanelname');
    tabPanel.setActiveItem(3); //index number 3 
}
```